# Weblogic Datasource connection

Tags: java, database, oracle11g, weblogic, datasource

I'm trying to access a datasource connection via Java client with this code:

```
Connection conn;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

try {
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
prop.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(prop);
Object obj = ctx.lookup("test/datasource");
System.out.println("Data Source Found….");

DataSource ds = (DataSource) obj;
conn = ds.getConnection();
System.out.println("Data Source User Name::"+conn.getMetaData().getUserName());
stmt = conn.createStatement();

String query = "select 1 from dual";
System.out.println("Query " + query);
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
if (rs != null) {
    System.out.println("Some Data Found in Query");
} else {
    System.out.println("No Data Found in Query");
}
ctx.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But i got the following stack trace. I can't figure out what happening. Someone knows?

Data Source Found…

Feb 13, 2012 4:07:28 PM GMT-03:00 Info JDBC BEA-001155 The following exception has occurred:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getCachedWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:55)
    at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:202)
    at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:190)
    at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.createWrapper(WrapperFactory.java:175)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory.getWrapper(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:197)
    at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.SerialConnection.readResolve(SerialConnection.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1061)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1762)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:197)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:564)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:193)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ObjectIO.readObject(ObjectIO.java:62)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:240)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:348)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_1031_WLStub.getConnection(Unknown Source)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you opened WebLogic console and verified whether everything is OK with your DataSource? Is it testable from the web console?

Comment: Does this appear in the sysout? `System.out.println("Data Source Found….");`

Comment: Thanks guys. I already solved the problem. I simply changed the connection string on the weblogic console to a format like jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=OCDB)(INSTANCE_NAME=OCDB_1))). It's weird, but worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Weblogic 10.3 and above best fool proof solution (That does not make you scratch your head) is:

Include just the wlfullclient.jar found in 
${wlserver_10.3_installation_home}\server\lib folder

in you class path (lib). This way you do not need weblogic.jar

If you do not find the wlfullclient.jar then build it. Here is how you build it:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/client/jarbuilder.html

Then write this code:

```
//Some Code

weblogic.jndi.Environment env = new weblogic.jndi.Environment();
env.setInitialContextFactory(Environment.DEFAULT_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
env.setProviderUrl("t3://${weblogic_host_ip}:${weblogic_port_number}");
env.setSecurityPrincipal(${DB_USER});
env.setSecurityCredentials(${DB_PASSWORD});
java.lang.Object obj = null;
try {
            javax.naming.Context ctx = env.getInitialContext();
        obj = ctx.lookup(${JNDI_NAME_OF_DATA_SOURCE});
        javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) obj;
        java.sql.Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select '5' from dual");
        if(rs != null){
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }

    } catch (javax.naming.NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//Other Code ....
```